# How to mask email in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

How do I mask the email address string in PostgreSQL?

I want to mask email as follows
testemail@gmail.com into te*****il@gmail.com

- Unmask first two and last two character before the email domain (@
  symbol)
- Mask all characters between with *

I have tried to address using

- `POSITION` to identify @ symbol
- `LENGTH` of characters left of `POSITION`

However PostgreSQL doesn't have a neat solution similar to excel `=REPLACE (old_text, start_num, num_chars, new_text)`  where you get to set the `start_num` and `num_chars`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT overlay(
          'testemail@gmail.com'
           placing repeat('*',
                          position('@' in 'testemail@gmail.com') - 5
                         )
           from 3
           for position('@' in 'testemail@gmail.com') - 5
       );

       overlay       
---------------------
 te*****il@gmail.com
(1 row)
```

You can create an SQL function out of that for comfort:

```
CREATE FUNCTION mask_email(text) RETURNS text
   LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE AS
$$SELECT overlay($1 placing repeat('*', position('@' in $1) - 5) from 3 for position('@' in $1) - 5)$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

To mask emails in PostgreSQL you can use [regexp_replace](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) function.

It has the syntax `regexp_replace(source, pattern, replacement [, start [, N ]] [, flags ])`.

SQL query:

```
SELECT t.email, 
       regexp_replace(t.email, '(.{2}(.+)(.{2})(@.+))', '$1*****$3$4') AS masked_email 
  FROM tbl t;
```

Output:

```
| email               | masked_email        |
|---------------------|---------------------|
| testemail@gmail.com | te*****il@gmail.com |
```

Comment: do you know how this could be adapted to mask all emails contained within a varchar array?